# Generate and download a specific instance of a variable font with .JS/.JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, fonts, instance

I've designed a variable font and now I'm just finishing to develop a website where It's possible to test Its multiple configurations throught input sliders. I would like to give the users the possibility to download a static .ttf instance setted with slider-defined bespoke values, but I don't even know where to start. Any advice is welcome! Thanks

Comment: This may not be an appropriate post - you want to ask a specific question or for specific information (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). This seems to be more of a general request for a lot of different pieces of help. Can you narrow this down to something specific you'd like to know?

Comment: Of course, I'll try! Is it possible to generate and download a static .ttf instance of a variable font with its current CSS "font-variation-settings" values?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have those different font files statically available, or have a way of generating them at runtime. Google's font hosting service is dynamic and lets you choose just the font styles you want. They then package them up into a Zip file and let you download them; they also let you simply link to it in CSS so you're just getting the fonts you want and letting them run. You would need to have that setup. I believe Google has already generated all the different font files that would be possible, and just lets you take what you need. For your site, you would simply need to use JavaScript to look at the settings and generate the appropriate URL.